# Остановка процесса перед выключением (перезагрузкой) системы [Centos 6.4]

Tags: cron

Есть сервер TeamSpeak 3, сервер запускается командой

```
./ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

Если просто перезагрузить сервер, то список каналов сбрасывается, поэтому надо завершать процесс командой

```
./ts3server_startscript.sh stop
```

Как прописать в CRON-е или планировщике заданий завершение работы процесса (таким образом) перед **КАЖДЫМ** выключением или перезагрузкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не крон нужен а start-stop init script.

Создаете скрипт запуска - останова, основываясь на **/etc/init.d/skeleton**. Далее в нужный runlevel кидаете symbolic link, который будет запускать init script при старте , называете его S[порядковый номер запуска]teamspeak, например **S22teamspeak**. И в 6 и 0 runlevel кидаете symbolic link который запустит init script останова, называете его K[порядковый номер запуска]teamspeak, например **K22teamspeak**. Результат - это запуск сервиса при загрузке, останов при перезагрузке и выключении.